# ListView DataItem Shows Null

Tags: c#, asp.net, listview

A few days ago, I [wrote about issues](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/583689/dictionaryt-of-listt-and-listviews-in-asp-net) with implementing a ListView in ASP.NET.  Now, with all of the other code written, I'm having trouble saving changed items in a ListView.

A few things of note:

- The Save button is not part of the ListView proper; it calls the `GetListViewItems()` method, which in turns call the `Save()` method.
- The `Listview.DataBind()` event is invoked when a button is pressed requesting the records to be updated
- The Listview shows text using `<%#Eval("Key.Name") %>` and a [named `DropDownList`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/595761/concatenating-two-properties-for-display-in-a-dropdownlist) using `<%#Eval("Value") %>`

#### Getting The Items From the ListView

```
public void GetListViewItems()
{
 List<Foo> Result = FooManager.CreateFooList();
 DropDownList ddl = null;
 ListViewItem Item = null;
    try
      {
       foreach (ListViewDataItem item in lvFooList.Items)
         {
          Item = item;
          ddl = ((DropDownList) (Item.FindControl("ddlListOfBars")));
          if (//something is there)
           {
            Foo foo = FooManager.CreateFoo();
            foo.Id = item.DataItemIndex; //shows null
            int barId = int.Parse(ddl.SelectedItem.Value); //works just fine
            foo.barId = barId;
            Result.Add(foo);
           }
         }
      }
   catch (Exception ex)
     {
             //Irrelevant for our purposes
     }
}
```

#### DataBinding the ListView

The code to databind the ListView is [shown here in my previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/583689/dictionaryt-of-listt-and-listviews-in-asp-net).

#### Question(s):

1. Why is it that when I iterate through the `ListViewDataItem` in the `Listview` that each item is `null`?
2. How can I retrieve the `Foo.Id` from the Dictionary?
3. What else might I be missing?
4. What would I use if I wanted to get that `Id` Programmatically based on what items were shown?  As it is now, the current ListView is shown based on what `Foo`s were selected.  Those `Foo`s selected are then displayed, and the user can change the `Bar` in the `DropDownList`, hit Save, and those changes are propogated.

---

#### Update

As it turns out, my problem was what [leppie](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/609276/listview-dataitem-shows-null/609331#609331) had said; and that was that I needed to specify `DataKeyNames` and use those to retain the information from the ListView.

Here's the code I added:

```
try
{
   int DataKeyArrayIndex = 0;
   foreach (ListViewDataItem item in lvFooList.Items)
     {
      Item = item;
      ddl = ((DropDownList) (Item.FindControl("ddlListOfBars")));
      if (//something is there)
       {
        Foo foo = FooManager.CreateFoo();
        Foo tempFoo = FooManager.CreateFoo();
        if (lvFooList != null)
        {
             tempFoo = ((Foo)(lvFooList.DataKeys[DataKeyArrayIndex].Value));
        }
         
        foo.Id = tempFoo.Id;
        int barId = int.Parse(ddl.SelectedItem.Value); //works just fine
        foo.barId = barId;
        Result.Add(foo);
        DataKeyArrayIndex++;
     }
   }
}
```

And then in the `.ascx` file, I added `DataKeyNames="Key"`, like so:

```
<asp:ListView ID="lvFooList" runat="server" DataKeyNames="Key">
```

This allowed me to use the `Key` [from my previous post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/583689/dictionaryt-of-listt-and-listviews-in-asp-net) to determine which Foo was being looked at.

Any critiques of this approach, as well as methods for making it better are greatly appreciated.

Comment: Edited to fix a problem documented here: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/26661/bug-in-rendered-question

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Some quick answers:

1. Your need to use databinding for that to work, in other words, assign to `DataSource` and call `DataBind()`. EDIT: seems you are doing that. But remember it wont persist between postbacks, just the `DataKey` (see below).
2. If I recall correctly, you need to specify the `DataKeyNames`, and they can be retrieved from the `DataKey` property then.

Comment: The post I linked to shows how it's bound. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/583689/dictionaryt-of-listt-and-listviews-in-asp-net

Comment: FWIW, I'm hesitant to upvote or accept your answer without more clarity. My problem centers around not 'getting' what I'm missing with the ListView; so I'm hoping someone will be able to point to exactly what I'm missing/doing wrong.

Comment: It's ok, it's been a while since I did ASP.NET, someone else can probably give a more direct answer  :)

Answer (score 6):

you can also use the ListViewDataItem.DataItemIndex property instead of keeping your own index, as in:

```
foreach (ListViewDataItem item in MyListView.Items)
{
    // in this example key is a string value
    Foo foo = new Foo(MyListView.DataKeys[item.DataItemIndex].Value as string);

    // do stuff with foo
}
```