# Databind List of Integers

Tags: asp.net, data-binding

I've got the following list of integers:

```
Dim foo = New List(Of Integer)
```

I set the datasource of my gridview to foo.  What do I put in my databinding markup?

```
<%# Eval("???") %>
```

Comment: Could you show the complete code?

Comment: Here's a hint as to what I'm looking for: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/583689/dictionaryt-of-listt-and-listviews-in-asp-net

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This should work:

```
<%# Container.DataItem %>
```